# Invalid Redeclaration of SocketIOManger with swift in ios

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

import UIKIt

Class SocketIOManager : NSObject {

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SocketIOManager class already exist in your socketIO framework, therefore you do not need to create another class for It. I think this is happening with you.

Answer (score 2):

SocketIOManager already exists in Socket.IO, you need to prefix your class with your own prefix:

```
Class MySocketIOManager : SocketIOManager {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actaully Class name with SocketIOManager is  already defined in SocketIO-CLient Swift Library thats why it was showing this error .